# Checking for null only gets "Cannot read property '1' of null" in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

I am trying to test for a null value after a # in a string. I have tried it various ways but I always get a Cannot read property '1' of null when submitting test data. I have ferreted out the errors I can think of but this one I cannot seem to get around. Please keep in mind I am a beginner at this, I haven't programmed since cobol days and the last time i worked on javascript was in the early 2000s.

//start test data, 5 possible strings that may pass through

```
elt.message = '#1a' //goes through the script good
elt.message = '#12b' // goes through
elt.message = '#123c' //goes through
elt.message = '' //is ignored
elt.message = '# ' //crashes server
```

//end test data

```
//First lets test to see if # is in the message. If true then we will parse it and add it to the database.
var str = elt.message;
var substr = '#';
var vtest = str.indexOf(substr) > -1;
if (vtest == 1){
var Vname = elt.author;
console.log('We tested for # and the value is true');

//extracts the number and the letter after the # from incoming chat messages
var test = elt.message; // replace with message text variable. 
var pstr = test.match(/#(\d{1,3})([a-zA-Z])/);
if (pstr) {
var numbers = pstr[1];
var character = pstr[2];
var chupp = character.toUpperCase(); //Converts the lowercase to uppercase
}

//Tests to see if neither the question number or the possible answer is left out
//if (pstr[1] !== '' && pstr[2] !== ''){ //doesn't work =(
if (pstr[1] !== null && pstr[2] !== null){ //doesn't work either =(

console.log('we processed the numbers after the #sign and assigned the numbers and letter into variables.')
console.log('The question number is: ' + pstr[1]);
console.log('The letter processed is: ' + pstr[2]);

// Grabs the date and converts it into the YYYYMMDD string.
var dobj = new Date();
var dstr = dobj.toString();
var dsplit = dstr.split(' ');
let currentdate = `${dobj.getMonth() < '9' ? `0${dobj.getMonth() + 1}` :
  dobj.getMonth() + 1}`;
  currentdate = `${dsplit[3]}${currentdate}${dsplit[2]}`;
console.log(currentdate)//remove when done

//checks to see what the highest question number is in the database
var sel = con.query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE ClassID = "+ currentdate + " ORDER BY QuesID DESC LIMIT 1", function (err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Total number of question records: '+result[0].QuesID);
    console.log('the script is querying with' + pstr[1]);
    console.log('the scripts answer letter is ' + pstr[2]);

    if (pstr[2] != '' && pstr[1] <= result[0].QuesID ){
        var query =  con.query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE ClassID = " + currentdate + " AND QuesID = " + pstr[1], function (err, result) { // Selects the record based on the Date and the question number variables provided above
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('it got past the test')

    if (result[0].AnsweredFirst === '' && result[0].AnswerLetter === chupp) { //Test to see if the AnsweredFirst is empty and that the Answer letter matchs with whats on file
    console.log('MATCH!');//remove when done

    var sql = "UPDATE questions SET AnsweredFirst = '"+ Vname + "' WHERE ClassID = " + currentdate + " AND QuesID = " + pstr[1]; //Updates the record with the first person who answered the question in the AnsweredFirst field
     con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(Vname + " answered question " + pstr[1] + " First!");
     });
    }
  });
 }
});
} else {
    console.log('Either the question number or the letter was left blank so we are skipping'); //the viewer did not put in a proper number and letter after the # sign
    }
} else {
    console.log('No signs of # so skipping queries') //if there is no # sign the message is not processed 
    };
```

I added the rest of the script to get a better idea. Messages are passed to the server from a chat client.

I'll give it a try moving the block of code into the first if statement. I know its messy but honestly i am surprised I got this far.

Comment: If your regular expression doesn't match then `pstr` will be `null`, so `pstr[1]` will give an error. Move those tests inside the existing `if(pstr) { ... }` block. *"a null value after a # in a string"* - Strings can't contain embedded null values, unless you are looking for a substring `"null"`. Can you please [edit] your question to show some example inputs with the corresponding desired outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var pstr = test.match(/#(\d{1,3})([a-zA-Z])/);`

means that if no match is found for your regex, then `pstr` is `null`

in that case any index of `pstr` (like pstr[1], pstr[2]) will throw the error you described:

> Cannot read property 'n' of null

**Solution:**

Before using indexes, check if the variable has a value or not

```
if(pstr !== null) {
    // do something with pstr[1]
}
```

**Edit:**

And as [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) rightly pointed out, you cannot explicitly *store* a null value in a string.

Comment: I tried that using if 
    (pstr[1] !== null && pstr[2] !== null){ but it wouldn't work.

Comment: that's wrong. when your object is null, you cannot read it's property (and compare it with null). You have to check the object itself for null

Comment: if(pstr !== null) { 
        // do something with pstr[1]
   }

This worked like a charm! No more crashing, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Look. If your test string did not match your regular expression then `pstr` assigned to null. Besides in next `if` condition you tried to check first element of `pstr` without checking it on null value:

```
if (pstr[1] !== null && pstr[2] !== null){ //doesnt work either =(
```

So, I think you need either add `pstr!==null` in second `if` or move all condition branch from this `if` inside then part of previous one `if` statement.